# rails simple_form disable form class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, simple-form

Is is possible to disable the form class="" for rails simple_form?
already tried :class => false to no avail.

```
= simple_form_for profiles_path, :method => :get  do |f|
```

I don't want something like this:

```
<form class="simple_form /profiles" method="get" action="/people" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

But I want something like this

```
<form class="" method="get" action="/people" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: No news on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a workaround but could you just use class="dummy" and then define that class as just being empty, e.g. in .css just `.dummy` then the next tag styles?

Comment: No that does not work :class => "empty" for example does not apply the class name